# IntelliJ print test run dependencies

Tags: scala, unit-testing, intellij-idea, sbt, classpath

I am working on a scala project which uses sbt for build tools. When we run unit tests on command line 'sbt test', the tests are running fine. However, when I run unit tests in IntelliJ, it seems to be picking up incorrect version of a dependency as well.

I was wondering if there is a way for me to print the classpath that IntelliJ is running the unit tests with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA already does that, actually, for each test run.
Tests are run as an invocation of JVM with the classpath passed to command-line parameter.

You need to press on the ellipsis to see the whole command line.
Classpath will be there after `-classpath` argument.
It's better to copy it to another window and enable line wrapping for the further digging.

[image: screenshot]